# Can I speed up QueryPerformanceTimer in VBA

Tags: windows, performance

MS says QPC can take as long as 800+nSec if it has to go to the motherboard to get the timing info (ref below).  It looks like my Gigabyte AERO does this...about 850 nSec for calls to QPC, QPF, GetSystemTimeAsPrecisionFile time. My QPF is 10 MHz so tick time for QPC happens to be 100 nSec, same as the fixed tick time for FIlETIME of GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime.  I am a bit surprised that a modern machine with high end CPU (Windows 10 Pro, I7-10875H with hyperthreading off since I am using VBA which is single thread, up to 4.9 GHz full speed) has QPC calls that are longer than 8 ticks of the clock for these timing functions.  Native VBA TIMER  only takes 60 nSec per call.

Are there settings or some other way to force the system to use a faster CPU based tick info rather than going to the motherboard? (I guess force it to use TSC register?).  BTW MS warns that you should not try to use these registers directly, apparently it is complicated and prone to user errors.

[Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps)
[Acquiring high-resolution time stamps - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps)

> What is the computational cost of calling QPC? The computational
> calling cost of QPC is determined primarily by the underlying hardware
> platform. If the TSC register is used as the basis for QPC, the
> computational cost is determined primarily by how long the processor
> takes to process an RDTSC instruction. This time ranges from 10s of
> CPU cycles to several hundred CPU cycles depending upon the processor
> used. If the TSC can't be used, the system will select a different
> hardware time basis. Because these time bases are located on the
> motherboard (for example, on the PCI South Bridge or PCH), the
> per-call computational cost is higher than the TSC, and is frequently
> in the vicinity of 0.8 - 1.0 microseconds depending on processor speed
> and other hardware factors. This cost is dominated by the time
> required to access the hardware device on the motherboard.

Comment: Re: `Native VBA TIMER only takes 60 nSec per call.` - but at what resolution?

Comment: Vlad, let me rephrase…obviously if you are OK with up to 15mSec error in timing, use VBA native timer like TIMER. This seems to be best built directly into VBA can do.   If you need better, like I do for this project, use something that is native to Windows, which I infer to be QPC when it uses the TSC register.  However, on my two laptops, it looks like QPC goes the route that MS mentions and is “native to the motherboard” and is therefor the slowest possible timer method.  SO…is there a setup issue where I can “flip some switches” to force the QPC call native to windows and speed it up?

Comment: Are you sure you are not measuring the time VBA takes to call a native API? Did you try the same measurement from a C++ compiled code?

Comment: Good call, Vlad.  I was blinded by the fact that the call cycle time for QPT was "exactly" the same time as mentioned in the MS doc.  I tried various API calls, including FileTimeToLocalFileTime which really should be mostly algebra.  They all were very close to the same elapsed time, fastest was about 740nSec.  Really disappointing but I guess I have to live with it since I only know VBA. For future reference, would C++ add in to VBA be faster do you think (not that I know how to do this now but I may need speed boost later).

Comment: Frankly, I don't think that calling  C++ add-in can be faster than calling some native API. But I am not a VBA person, so you should ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Vlad, thanks for all your help.  I was looking on how to set my first "answered" flag, but I do not see how to do this....I am guessing we used "Comments" , which can't be checked by me as an accepted answer.  The answer IMO is that this amount of time is normal for an API call from VBA, so cannot be speed it up, and it is not  because the call goes to the motherboard timing hardware rather than native windows resource.  Just live with it!

Comment: You can only accept an "Answer" (which this isn't; I simply expressed my suspicion). I do appreciate the gesture, don't worry about it.

Comment: Please see the article linked in this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/exporting-c-code-excel-quick-painless-tutorial-antoine-savine. Looks like a C++ beginner how-to for VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally found a few comments on cost of API calls [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002028/windows-api-how-expensive-is-it-to-call-an-api-function).

Following up on Vlad's useful comments, I believe the answer is I ***can't*** speed up QUERYPERFORMANCECOUNTER with some tricks/best practices.  I had assumed the ugly 800nSec+ call time was due to accessing the mother board because this time cost matched what MS was discussing for MB access time issues.  I timed other VBA API function calls and they all seem to need at least 800nSec on my 5GHz/8CPU core machine. So API calls from VBA are just slow. Really hurts if they are in high speed loops!